# AWK get a text following the header line

Tags: shell, awk, posix

I have this input data:

```
bar
foo

requires
league/flysystem ^1.0
symfony/console ^5.1

requires (dev)
phpunit/phpunit ^8
```

there is no new line char in the input data after the `phpunit/phpunit ^8`. The input data comes from piping it to AWK.

I would like to get with two separate AWK commands entries under `requires` and `requires (dev)`

first AWK script should produce:

```
league/flysystem ^1.0
symfony/console ^5.1
```

and second

```
phpunit/phpunit ^8
```

How to write these two AWK scripts?

So far I came up with a partial answer to the first script:

```
awk '/^requires/,/^requires \(dev\)/ { print }'
```

but it returns:

```
requires
league/flysystem ^1.0
symfony/console ^5.1

requires (dev)
```

Comment: If it's true that `there is no new line char in the input data after the phpunit/phpunit ^8. The input data comes from piping it to AWK.` then that awk script is broken because it's outputting something that isn't a valid POSIX text file. You should fix that,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
... | awk 'f&&!NF{exit} f; /^requires \(dev\)$/{f=1}'
```

change the pattern to match the first one.

**Explanation**

`f&&!NF{exit}` if the flag is set exit when there is an empty line

`f` print lines if the flag is set

`/.../{f=1}` set the flag when the pattern is found

essentially equivalent to `awk -v RS= '/pattern/{print; exit}'` without printing the pattern line.